# Criar uma div no topo do blog (wordpress) para flutuar fixamente ao rolar para baixo

Tags: html, css, html5, wordpress, css3

Tenho um blog, Queria exibir um anúncio em uma div depois que os usuários rolar para baixo e assim logo do site não esteja visível essa div apareça, e se voltar a subir ela desapareça. link do site http://maroclub.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha tem uma solução com jquery

```
$(function(){
    var nav = $('.classDiv');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 95) {
            nav.show();
        } else {
            nav.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Esse código mostrara a div quando o topo do site subir 95px, você pode aumentar o valor caso queira que aparace mais a baixo, no caso, é so trocar ".classDiv" pela div que estiver manipulando.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(function(){
  var nav = $('.objeto');
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 95) {
    nav.fadeIn();
   } else {
    nav.fadeOut();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.conteudo {
  height: 700px;
}
.objeto {
  position: fixed;  
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
  <div class="objeto">
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67174/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-pereira-criar-uma-div-no-topo-do-blog-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Google Adsense</title> 
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(function(){
  var nav = $('.objeto');
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
    nav.fadeIn();
   } else {
    nav.fadeOut();
   }
  });
 });
});
</script>

<script async="async" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>

 googletag.cmd.push(function() {

    var slot1 = [];
    slot1 [0] = googletag.defineSlot("/21643740994/BannerTopoDoArtigo", [728, 90], "div-gpt-ad-1507778867385-0"). addService(googletag.pubads());//);

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().setTargeting("Saude", ["Beleza", 'Dieta', 'Emagrecimento', 'Perder peso', 'produtos', 'Produtos de beleza', 'Receitas', 'Saude', 'Saúde', 'beleza emagrecimento']);  
    googletag.enableServices();
    setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);}, 30000);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<!-- /21643740994/BannerTopoDoArtigo -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1507778867385-0" style="height:90px; width:100%; position: fixed; background-color: red; display: none !important; top: 0px;" class="objeto">
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1507778867385-0"); });
</script>
</div>
<div style="height:2000px;whdth:100%;background-color:#999;margin-top:0px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para começar a mostrar o banner basta agir no valor `200` desse linha `if($(document).scrollTop()>200){`

```js
    var div = $('.banner');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(document).scrollTop()>200){
          var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
          div.css('opacity', 0 + percent);
       }else{
          div.css('opacity', 0);
       }

    });
```

```css
.encheLinguissa {
  height: 1200px;
} 
  
.banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #00e676;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='encheLinguissa'>

</div>

<div class="banner">
<div id='div' style="height:90px; width:720px; margin:0 auto;">
<img border="0" src="http://www.jalr.org/images/720x90.png">
</div>
</div>
```

> transition - faz com que a transição ocorra suavemente em um tempo determinado.
>   Quanto maior o valor (1.5) em `transition: opacity 1.5s;` mais suave a transição.